# Estimating $|\mu_1 - \mu_2|$ in a mixture of two Gaussians with known variance.

Tags: statistics, order-statistics, gaussian

Consider $n$ samples denoted with $X^n = X_1, \ldots, X_n$ from mixture of two Gaussians with equal variance and equal mixture proportions:

$X^n \sim 1/2 \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, 1) + 1/2 \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, 1)$.

Now the goal is to estimate the difference in means $|\mu_1 - \mu_2|$ from this $n$ samples. One idea is to rank them from lowest to highest, and take the difference between the 1/4th highest and lowest sample point. But how accurate is this estimate, and is there a better way?

Comment: Another approach might be to find the expected sample variance as a function of $|\mu_1 - \mu_2|$, or the distribution of the sample variance, and then compare this to the observed sample variance

Comment: The problem is that we can determine that $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)$. Therefore, the resulting distribution for $(\mu_1,\mu_2)=(1,5)$ is _exactly_ the same as for $(\mu_1,\mu_2) = (0,6)$. However the difference in means is not the same, therefore we do not have enough information to answer the question, purely from the sample $X^n$.

Comment: Edit: variance is supposed to be $1/2$ instead of $1/4$.

Comment: I don't think so. The variance of the mixture depends on the difference of the means, it is: $1 + (\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2)/2 - ((\mu_1+\mu_2)/2)^2$. Also, the mixture is not a normal distribution (imagine two Gaussians lying somewhat apart, then the mixture is bimodal).

Comment: The MLE has no closed form indeed. I would like to have an estimate together with an error bound.

Comment: Considering that I have some limited background in chromatography, I would expect a decent analytical result only in the regime of large $|\mu_1-\mu_2|$; at least larger than 2, ideally larger than 6. In this case you should be able to classify most of the samples as coming from one normal or the other and then average them separately to get the respective values of $\mu$. Without this assumption, the overlap region matters and there is just no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

The first two moments of this mixture are:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2}{2}+1$$
Substituting the true expectation by their respective means:
$$S_1=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$$
$$S_2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k^2$$
We can transform the system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
S_1 = \frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2} \\
S_2 = \frac{\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2}{2}+1
\end{cases}
$$
To get:
$$
\begin{cases}
\mu_1+\mu_2 = 2S_1 \\
\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2 = 2S_2 - 1
\end{cases}
$$
Now, knowing that $(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2=2(x^2+y^2)$ or equivalently $(x-y)^2=2(x^2+y^2) - (x+y)^2$ we can obtain the value of:
$$(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2 = 4(S_2-S_1^2-1)$$
And so:
$$|\mu_1-\mu_2| = 2\sqrt{S_2-S_1^2-1}$$
This estimator is at least consistent. Moreover, both $S_1$ and $S_2$ will be asymptotically normal. They are definitely not independent though and I don't even know about their covariance (though I suspect that their asymptotic distribution is jointly normal so the covariance is the only factor deciding their dependence). It is therefore not easy (at least not for me) to compute the bounds for the error of this estimator other than the MC simulation.